# how to write the condition?

Tags: php

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
print "<li>";                    // 1 line 
foreach ($tree as $term ) {      // 2 lines
   $diffdepth=0;
   if ($term->depth > $depth) {
      print "<ul class='haschild'><li>";
      $depth = $term->depth;
   }
```

the above is the original code, now I want according to `$term->depth > $depth`  make a condition to output.( `print "<li>";`  ) this line.

namely,

```
if ($term->depth > $depth) { 
   echo '<li class="parent">'; 
} 
else { 
   print "<li>"; 
}
```

but `$term->depth` can use after foreach loop, but i want to use it at 1 line, how do i do?

Comment: what you mean by 2 line line as you show or you mean by after 2 result ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print`ing in-line, assign your desired output to variables and then send it to the browser after the logic is complete.

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
$parent = ""; // 1 line 
$child  = "";
foreach ($tree as $term) { // 2 line
    $diffdepth=0;
    if ($term->depth > $depth) {
        $parent = "<li class='parent'>";
        $child .= "<ul class='haschild'><li>";
        $depth = $term->depth;
    } else {
        $parent = "<li>";
    }
}
echo $parent . $child;
```

Please note you'll need to finish this up by adding all the applicable `</li>`s and whatnot, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter:

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($tree as $term)
{
    ...
    if ($term->depth > $depth)
    {
        if ($counter == 0) { echo '<li class="parent">'; }
        else { echo '<li>'; }
        print "<ul class='haschild'><li>";
        $depth = $term->depth;
    }
    ...
    $counter++;
}
```

If you need to write more differences based on your condition, you can turn tha above into:

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($tree as $term)
{
    ...
    if ($term->depth > $depth)
    {
        if ($counter == 0) { echo '<li class="parent">'; }
        print "<ul class='haschild'><li>";
        $depth = $term->depth;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($counter == 0) {  echo '<li>'; }
        ...
    }
    ...
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to build something like parent child hierarchy then you should check it [by click here](http://dipesharea.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/n-level-category/#more-60)